# Can i write a single plugin in phonegap-cordova which can be integrated in all native and hybrid application as third party tool?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

> I am new to mobile development.I have recent business requirement in
>   which i have to write in app plugin code for my client for their
>   already exiting application in ios and android. Client should be
>   easily able to integrate my pugin in their app.
>
> The problem i facing now is client can have their app in native code
>   or it can be a phonegap ( hybrid ) app  as well. So if i go full
>   native i have to write one for ios , one for android. On top of this
>   if client have hybride app i need to write one phonegap plugin as well
>   (i am not sure about this) ?
>
> I went through  https://www.helpshift.com/ and
>   https://www.uservoice.com/ and they seems to have three in app for ios
>   native , android native and for phonegap. Does there is obvious reason
>   for this ? would like to know ? To some my question
>
> - Can i write a single plugin in app in phonegap cordova which can be integrated in all native and hybrid application ? This would help me
>     as am working on javascript for a while and would be great to maintain
>     a single source code.
>
>   - If no , what is the best practice ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if understanding your question. Correct me if I'm wrong: you need a piece of code for Android and for iOS that could work as a cordova plugin as well?

In this case I think you could write your source code for each platform (as it should be written anyway for a cordova plugin), and then write a wrapper for cordova:

**Android:**

YourAwesomeClass.java

```
class YourAwesomeClass {
  public void yourAwesomeMethod() {
  }
}
```

CordovaPluginForYourAwesomeClass.java:

```
class CordovaPluginForYourAwesomeClass extends CordovaPlugin {
  YourAwesomeClass yac;

  public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
    yac = new YourAwesomeClass();
  }

  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    PluginResult result = null;

    if ("yourJsHook".equals(action)) {
      result = executeYourJsHook(args, callbackContext);

    } else {
      return false;
    }

    if (result != null) {
      callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
    }

    return true;
  }

  private PluginResult executeYourJsHook(JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    yac.yourAwesomeMethod();
    callbackContext.success();
    return null;
  }
}
```

**iOS:**

YourAwesomeClass.h:

```
@interface YourAwesomeClass {
}
-(void) yourAwesomeMethod;
```

YourAwesomeClass.m:

```
@implementation YourAwesomeClass
  -(void) yourAwesomeMethod {
  }
@end
```

CordovaPluginForYourAwesomeClass.h:

```
@interface CordovaPluginForYourAwesomeClass : CDVPlugin {
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) YourAwesomeClass *yac;
-(void) yourJsHook: (CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command;
```

CordovaPluginForYourAwesomeClass.m:

```
@interface CordovaPluginForYourAwesomeClass
  @synthesize yac;

  -(CDVPlugin *)initWithWebView:(UIWebView *)theWebView {
    self = (CDVAdMobAds *)[super initWithWebView:theWebView];
    yac = [YourAwesomeClass init];
    return self;
  }
  -(void) yourJsHook: (CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult;
    NSString *callbackId = command.callbackId;
    NSArray* args = command.arguments;

    [yac yourAwesomeMethod];

    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
  }
@end
```

yourAwesomeJsBridge.js:

```
yourAwesomeJsBridge.yourJsHook = function(success, failure, options) {
  cordova.exec(success, failure, "CordovaPluginForYourAwesomeClass", "yourJsHook", [ options ]);
}
```

For native code you could use YourAwesomeClass and for cordvoa apps you should use your plugin ([see Cordova Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide))

You can look at the source code for cordova plugin in the cordova plugin repository.